# What does this ocaml syntax mean?

Tags: syntax, ocaml, ml

```
type 'k leaf = {a_bb : 'k -> string;}
```

I'm unable to understand what this line of code in ocaml means. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It declares a new type `leaf` parametrised over a type variable `'k` which is a record type with one field `a_bb` of type `'k -> string` where `'k` is the parameter we mentioned before.

An example of a value of type `'k leaf` would be:

```
{ a_bb = fun _ -> "Hello World!" }
```

But the `'k` can also be specialised to a concrete type e.g.

```
{ a_bb = fun b -> if b then "Hello World!" else "Argh!" }
```

has the type `bool leaf` because the argument to the function in the field `a_bb` has to be a boolean for the expression `if b then (...)` to make sense.

You can access the function in the field `a_bb` by using a projection like so:

```
fun v -> v.a_bb
```